# ESP8266 BJT (bc547b)

Tags: arduino, transistors, esp8266

i want to make expansion PCB for ESP8266 and i'have read many discussion for Arduino BJT connection, but still need to ensure is it working with esp8266 to switch on 20mA 24DC buzzer.

and also what is suitable value for those component ?

Below is the Schematic  :

[image]

Comment: 24 V is a fairly substantial voltage. The BJT may be fine for it, especially if there is enough base current (and we can't tell how much is needed because we don't know what the buzzer needs.) But there is always a risk with the I/O pin, especially if there is an accidental short. You'll have to write more about how much you value your ESP8266 (do you care a lot if it is damaged and are you willing to go to long lengths to protect it), and about the buzzer current requirements. If I had to guess, I'd say you can at least try this circuit without the IO pin. Just tie 3.3 V to R1 and see.

Comment: @jonk the buzzer need at least 20mA, okey, i will follow your instruction, for the Diode do you have any suggestion suitable part number for this ?

Comment: No. Most anything is okay. You probably can get away without one. But if you have a diode you can just use it.

Comment: okay i will follow as your suggestion 